# Script Bash Solaris SS7 Query signaling point

Tags: bash, solaris, ss7

I'm trying to do a script to display some configuration from the MML console (Man-Machine Language Interface) for SS7 using the file option:

```
cat /tmp/queryss7.txt 

display-sp:;
exit:;

mml -f /tmp/queryss7.txt 0

< ERROR >:: Input source ambiguous
```

But this error only shows up if I use the `crontab` to start the script. If I start manually the script works fine...

Thx

Comment: perhaps you need to source some environment variables first?

Comment: I already add it at the beginning of the script using
. /export/home/.profile